# Display Hierarchy Information from CTE in Horizontal manner

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had written  CTE in SQl which returns Hierarchy information as Mentioned below:-

```
         Ecode          Name           RoleID         ImmediateSupervisor       
            21441          Dharm          1          20479         
            20479          Sri        2          21567         
            21567          Ram        3          21111         
            21111          Anand          4          21134         
            21134          Raghu          5          Null          
            20182          Subbu          4          21134         
            21465          Deepak         4          21134         
            21131          Ajay           3          21465         
            31234          Kalyan         1          21131         
            21141          Hemanth        1          20479         
            25478          Mahesh         1          21567         
            45698          Laxman         1          20182
```

I want to display the result in Hierarchical manner in Horizontal like this:-

```
RoleID->    5   4   3   2   1
    Raghu   Anand   Ram     Mahesh
    Raghu   Anand   Ram Sri Dharm
    Raghu   Anand   Ram Sri Hemanth
    Raghu   Subbu           Laxman
    Raghu   Deepak  Ajay        Kalyan
```

Here in Result it is displaying the Hierarchy information in horizantal manner as per RoleID.
In case if their is any skipping then that RoleID Column willbe blank. For example you can see that Laxman(RoleID-1) is Reporting to Subbu(RoleID-4). Their is no other user lies in between laxman and Subbu , so in the result blanks are their For Column 3 and 2 column.

Please help me that how this can be achieved in SQl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write query as :

```
select 
T1.Name as [1],
    case 2 
    when T2.RoleID then T2.Name  
    when T3.RoleID then T3.Name 
    when T4.RoleID then T4.Name 
    when T5.RoleID then T5.Name 
    else null end as [2] ,
    case 3 
    when T2.RoleID then T2.Name  
    when T3.RoleID then T3.Name 
    when T4.RoleID then T4.Name 
    when T5.RoleID then T5.Name 
    else null end as [3] ,
    case 4
    when T2.RoleID then T2.Name  
    when T3.RoleID then T3.Name 
    when T4.RoleID then T4.Name 
    when T5.RoleID then T5.Name 
    else null end as [4] ,
    case 5
    when T2.RoleID then T2.Name  
    when T3.RoleID then T3.Name 
    when T4.RoleID then T4.Name 
    when T5.RoleID then T5.Name 
    else null end as [5] 
from table1 T1
left join table1  T2 on T1.ImmediateSupervisor  = T2.Ecode 
left join table1  T3 on T2.ImmediateSupervisor  = T3.Ecode 
left join table1  T4 on T3.ImmediateSupervisor  = T4.Ecode 
left join table1  T5 on T4.ImmediateSupervisor  = T5.Ecode 
where T1.RoleID = 1
```

Hope this helps!!!